# Git get number of changed files on status?

Tags: git, github

It's possible to get the number of files that have been modified on a git repository (in the last commit)?

Answer (score 3):

Use `--shortstat` along with your text-processing tools of choice. For example:

```
$ git log -1 --shortstat | tail -1 | cut -d, -f1
 1 file changed
```

See also `--name-status`, and `man git-log` for additional options.